# How to reinstall Windows 11 from .iso but keep using GRUB bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, windows, mbr

Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11 Insider Preview are installed on my ASUS TUF DASH F15 laptop in dual-boot mode with GRUB bootloader.

Since I left the Insider Program, I want to reinstall Windows 11 from the official .iso image.

My `/` partition is mounted on the same SSD drive as `:C` partition for Windows.

How can I safely reinstall Windows 11, while keeping Ubuntu on-place and safely boot on both systems with GRUB?

Comment: As long as you know how to install Windows by selecting a specific partition you should be able to do it safely. Then all it needs (or should need) is changing the UEFI boot order back to Ubuntu. In any case, of course, have backups AND Ubuntu live/installation media.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows, so make sure Windows fast start up or always on hibernation is off. Windows will reset UEFI to make Windows first, but major update to grub resets UEFI to make grub/ubuntu first. Or normal. You just have to use UEFI  to boot Ubuntu and reset boot order with efibootmgr or if HP reset boot order using UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu).